# Extracting and cleaning up duplicate emails

Tags: c#, performance

Right now I am using a regex to extract emails from a text document, and filter the duplicates out of this using the Distinct function from linq. After which I run the output file through a clean up of duplicates as well, as the program can be run several times over several different files.

Now my question, would there be a more optimal way of checking the output file for duplicates? Because as it is right now, the bigger the file, the longer it will take.

And I have the feeling there should be a less intense way to check this.

```
// Extractor
public void Mail(string file)
{
    string strRegex = @"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?";
    var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);

    var matches = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(file))
    {
        if (myMatch.Success)
        {
            matches.Add(myMatch.Value);
        }
    }

    var cleanMatch = matches.Distinct().ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < cleanMatch.Count; i++)
    {
        Log.Mail(cleanMatch[i]);
    }

    CleanDuplicates();
}

// Duplicate Cleaner
private void CleanDuplicates()
{
    var lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\EmailList.txt"));

    lines = lines.Distinct().ToList();
    string target = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\EmailList.txt";
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter newTask = new System.IO.StreamWriter(target, false))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            newTask.WriteLine(lines[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the order of the items in the file matter?

Comment: @RobH Order is unimportant

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll be able to simplify this a lot if you use a better in memory datastructure than a `List<T>`. You only want distinct items, `HashSet<T>` will generally be better here as it has O(1) lookups.

```
public void Mail(string file)
{
    var strRegex = @"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\+]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.([A-Za-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?";
    var myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
    var matches = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (Match matchedValue in myRegex.Matches(file))
    {
        // Changed per Mjolka's comment
        if (matches.Add(matchedValue.Value))
        {
            Log.Mail(matchedValue.Value);
        }
    }
    CleanDuplicates();
}
```

Note that I've removed the uneccessary check for `Success` on the `Match` object.

Your naming could do with a bit of work `myRegex` doesn't really mean anything.

You could also store the Regex as a field on the class to declutter this method.

You can leverage a `HashSet<string>` in your `CleanDuplicates` method too:

```
private void CleanDuplicates()
{
    var fileLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\EmailList.txt";

    var lines = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation));

    File.WriteAllLines(fileLocation, lines.ToArray());
}
```

Definitely add a `using System.IO` it removes a lot of clutter.

Prefer built in methods e.g. `File.WriteAllLines` overwrites the file or creates a new one - no need to whip out a `StreamWriter`.

Also note that if your file becomes really large this will start getting pretty slow.

**Final(?) Edit**

Can't use var in the foreach loop as MatchCollection implements `IEnumerable` only - not the generic version. Sorry about that.

In order to use a Linq method (such as `Select`) we have to supply the type by calling `Cast<T>`:

```
foreach (var matchedValue in myRegex.Matches(file).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value))
{
    if (matches.Add(matchedValue))
    {
        Log.Mail(matchedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: [`HashSet.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `bool` indicating if the item was added, so you can use that instead of the call to `Contains`.

Comment: Great point mjolka - I thought there was something that did that... Couldn't remember, should have looked at the docs.

Comment: matchedValue.Value doesn't work. With your edit, matchedValue returns as a object, make it a string matchedValue, or converting it to string in the loop fixes it though.

Comment: @MXD - I've actually put it through a compiler now so will edit with more details :)

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things.

```
var matches = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var myMatch in myRegex.Matches(file))
{
    if (myMatch.Success)
    {
        if(matches.Add(myMatch.Value))
        {
            Log.Mail(myMatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Use a hash set. If you add an item that is already in the list, it will ignore it. If the add is successful (it retuns a bool) then you can log it immediately.

You have written out to disk the discovered emails across multiple files. This is slow. I would suggest doing it in memory for the batch of files.

Comment: `You have written out to disk the discovered emails across multiple files. This is slow. I would suggest doing it in memory for the batch of files.` As I did not include the actual writer, it appends onto a existing file. Making 1 file grow bigger over time. As for the files it gets them from, they go one by one. So I am not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: All of this could be magnitudes more efficient if you'd use a HashSet<T>.

Answer (score 3):

```
var lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\EmailList.txt"));

lines = lines.Distinct().ToList();
string target = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\EmailList.txt";
using (System.IO.StreamWriter newTask = new System.IO.StreamWriter(target, false))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        newTask.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Calling `.ToList()` here is a pointless operation. `ToList` produces an indexable collection, but also evaluates everything in one go. Since all you're doing is iterating over the collection, stick with `IEnumerable` and use a foreach loop, as it makes your intentions clearer.

Secondly, you should be using `var` in your using statement, because the type of `newTask` is clear from the assignment.

You're duplicating your concatanation of the desktop directory and "EmailList.txt", as RobH says, put that in a string variable, and you'll only have to change that once. Better yet, refactor the magic string "EmailList.txt" into a const.

Why not use `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation anyway?

Lastly, I'm seeing a lot of fully-qualified types. Not just `System.IO`, but `System` too.

```
//Outside of method:
const EmailListFileName = "EmailList.txt";

//Inside of method:
var emailListPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), EmailListFileName);

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(emailListPath).Distinct();

using (var newTask = new StreamWriter(emailListPath, false))
{
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        newTask.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate that `MatchCollection` only implements the non-generic `ICollection` (though that's [being fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/271)), but we can use `Cast<T>` to get around that. This is how I would suggest writing the main part of the first method:

```
var emails = myRegex.Matches(file)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .Distinct();
foreach (var email in emails)
{
    Log.Mail(email);
}
```

`Distinct` is implemented using a hash set, so performance will be good.